# Looking for a Flash/JS-based SVG editor or editing framework

Tags: javascript, flash, editor, svg

I'm looking for a framework or library to create SVG images. It should run in the browser, so it should be based on Flash or maybe JavaScript. Up to now I found the Flash library by inevo.pt, the SVG editing component of Dojox, and some little JavaScript tools.

Is there anything else, preferrably stable and mature?

Thanks a lot in advance!

-- Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Exporting to svg is a pretty easy step to take.

[Draw & Export to svg from FLASH](http://memo.tv/drawing_and_exporting_svg_from_flash_as3)

[Example](http://memo.tv/files/memotv/SVGExport.swf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! If exporting to SVG is easy, we have more freedom choosing or implementing the actual editor.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen Raphael? http://raphaeljs.com/ This is a JS drawing framework that renders in SVG, Canvas, or VML depending on browser capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

[SVG-Edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com) ([demo](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html)) is coming along nicely. It's a basic editor which the developers plan to move to a plugin architecture to enable third-party tools. It integrates nicely with the MoinMoin wiki, to allow inline editable diagrams etc.

I think within a year there will be several good open source editors available, using different base JS libraries, now that the ground has been broken by [svg-edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you'd want this. Inkscape is cool but doesn't run in a browser.

Comment: I need it for a web-based direkt marketing solution. People shall be able to design postcards, flyers etc. The output shall be SVG for embedding in XSL-FO processing with Batik and FOP.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have some on http://svg.startpagina.nl

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Amaya http://www.w3.org/Amaya/